# Teaching data structures in C++, should I use smart pointers when introducing linked list?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, smart-pointers, nullptr

I'm currently teaching an introductory data structures course in C++. I don't have a ton of experience in C++ (Course used to be given in java), so I'm struggling a bit with whether or not I should use smart or raw pointers in simple data structures such as a linked list.

Below is my implementation of a linked list, using raw pointers. I'm confident it doesn't have memory leaks (Tested this), but I feel like smart pointers may provide a more elegant solution. for example, in the `display()` function, I check to see if the end of the list has been reached by comparing the current node with `nullptr`. for this to work, when I delete an element such as in `removeFront()` or `removeBack()`, I need to see if the head/tail respectively are `nullptrs`, and if they aren't, set the next/prev to `nullptr` explicitly. Otherwise, my display function's if the statement won't match the `nullptr` check, and it will try to access a node beyond the end of the list (in the case of calling `removeBack()`, and then `display()`). anyways just wondering what some c++ experts thought, the syntax of raw pointers is simpler, which is why I feel its preferable for teaching, but then again, smart pointers would probably help students develop better habits.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class DLLNode {
private:
    DLLNode() : next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
    int elem;
    DLLNode* next;
    DLLNode* prev;
    friend class DLL;
};

class DLL {
public:
    DLL() :head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
    ~DLL() {
        while (!empty())
            removeFront();
    }

    int front()const { return head->elem; }
    int back() const { return tail->elem; }

    bool empty()const { return head == nullptr; }

    void addFront(const int newElem) {
        DLLNode* v = new DLLNode;
        v->elem = newElem;
        if (head != nullptr) {
            head->prev = v;
            v->next = head;
        }
        else tail = v;

        head = v; 
    }

    void addBack(const int newElem) {
        DLLNode* v = new DLLNode; 
        v->elem = newElem; 
        if (tail != nullptr) {
            tail->next = v;
            v->prev = tail; 
        }
        else head = v; 

        tail = v; 
    }

    void addAfter(DLLNode* current, int newElem) {
        DLLNode* v = new DLLNode; 
        v->elem = newElem; 
        v->next = current->next; 
        v->prev = current; 
        if (v->next != nullptr)
            v->next->prev = v;
        else
            tail = v; 
    }

    void addBefore(DLLNode* current, int newElem){
        DLLNode* v = new DLLNode; 
        v->elem = newElem; 
        v->prev = current->prev; 
        v->next = current; 
        if (v->prev != nullptr)
            v->prev->next = v;
        else
            head = v; 
    }

    void removeFront() {
        DLLNode* old = head;
        head = old->next;
        if (head != nullptr)
            head->prev = nullptr; 
        delete old;
    }

    void removeBack() {
        DLLNode* old = tail; 
        tail = old->prev; 
        if (tail != nullptr)
            tail->next = nullptr; 
        delete old; 
    }


    void display() const {
        DLLNode* current = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            cout << "node position: " << counter++ << ", elem value: " << current->elem << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

private:
    DLLNode* head;
    DLLNode* tail;
};


  int main() {

    DLL list; 
    list.addFront(5);
    list.addFront(2);
    list.addBack(8); 
    list.addBack(99); 
    list.removeFront(); 
    list.removeBack();
    list.display(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This seems entirely opinion-based. I think https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ would be a better website to ask this sort of thing at.

Comment: Since it's a question about teaching, it depends what the learning objective is, and what the students' prior knowledge is - do you want the students to learn about the linked list data structure, or memory management? Do the students already have a strong understanding of smart pointers, or would that be a new topic? As @ggorlen points out, https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask this kind of question, but if you ask there then you should give more details about the context you are teaching in.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks, didn't know about that site. students have no knowledge of smart pointers coming into the class. just basic c++ (barely touched on classes).

Comment: @Dan yes i know, haha. i'll fix that when i give the example in class.

Comment: BTW, don't forget [the rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).